# Display each for loop iteration output in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, append, settext

I am trying demonstrate insertion sort triggered by button click. Showing all steps of sorting in output.

Input Integer single digit 0-9.

Can someone help me improvising my code!
Help would be much appreciated.

O/p displays braces and comas coz its an array.
Can i get o/p without braces and comas!?
instead of o/p [3,5,7,9] it should be like- 3 5 7 9

```
    public void btnClickMe(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    insertionSort();
}
public void insertionSort(){
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String text = et.getText().toString();
    String txt1 = text.replaceAll(","," ");
    String txt= txt1.replaceAll(" ","");
    int[] array = new int[txt.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++){
        array[i] = Character.getNumericValue(txt.charAt(i));
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.setText("Output:");
    for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++){
        int key = array[j];
        int i = j - 1;
        while ((i > -1) && (array[i] > key)){
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            i--;
        }
    }
    array[i + 1] = key;
    tv.append(Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(",","")+"\n");
}
```

I maybe asking too much but i m trying to learn android and your help will teach me many new things. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your insertion algorithm is flawed.
Second, you need to reset the `TextView`'s text before appending each time.

```
int[] array = {6, 4, 3, 2};
// TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
// Resets the text to be blank.
// tv.setText("");

for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    while (j > 0 && array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
        int temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j - 1];
        array[j - 1] = temp;
        --j;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    // i.e. [4, 6, 3, 2]
    // tv.append(Arrays.toString(array) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: I dont want to replace actually.
I want to display all iterations like eg:
I/p: 6432
O/p should be:
4 6 3 2
3 4 6 2
2 3 4 6
 using settext it only shows the last iteration ie; 2 3 4 6
I hope u got the question.

Comment: Then, what did you mean by --- "new o/p gets append instead of clearing the old o/p and displaying new array.?"

Comment: By that i mean:
if my i/p is 421
it shows o/p:
2 4 1
1 2 4.
and then when i insert new values (6 4 1) and click sort button
instead of textfield to show only
4 6 1
1 4 6
instead it shows
2 4 1
1 2 4(which is previous o/p) appended by new o/p
4 6 1
1 4 6
Sorry for such complicated questions.

Comment: If it --- "instead of textfield to show only 4 6 1 1 4 6 instead it shows 2 4 1 1 2 4(which is previous o/p) appended by new o/p 4 6 1 1 4 6"............Then, you need to use `setText` to clear the "previous o/p"

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Got it! I first used settext then appended the results! Thanks.